# SQL INNER JOIN more than 2 tables and Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have already tried the following:

```
SELECT categorias.categoria_nombre
    ,categorias.seccion
    ,tipo_item.nombre
    ,tipo_item.detalle
    ,items.codigo_barra
FROM categorias
INNER JOIN tipo_item ON (
        categorias.id = tipo_item.categoria
        AND categorias.secion = '$dato'
        AND categorias.categoria_nombre = '$dato_extra'
        )
INNER JOIN items ON (
        tipo_item.id = items.tipo_item
        AND $ESTADO
        ) LIMIT 100 OFFSET $offset
```

I have also tried like this:

```
SELECT categorias.categoria_nombre
    ,categorias.seccion
    ,tipo_item.nombre
    ,tipo_item.detalle
    ,items.codigo_barra
FROM categorias
INNER JOIN tipo_item ON categorias.id = tipo_item.categoria
INNER JOIN items ON tipo_item.id = items.tipo_item
WHERE categorias.secion = '$dato'
    AND categorias.categoria_nombre = '$dato_extra' LIMIT 100 OFFSET $offset
```

My query works without `WHERE` and the conditions, but is really important to have only the tables that matches these conditions.

Both of the queries I've written give me the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/showsupport/public_html/panel/filtro-general.php on line 323

It works like in this example:

```
SELECT categorias.categoria_nombre
    ,categorias.seccion
    ,tipo_item.nombre
    ,tipo_item.detalle
    ,items.codigo_barra
FROM categorias
INNER JOIN tipo_item ON categorias.id = tipo_item.categoria
INNER JOIN items ON tipo_item.id = items.tipo_item LIMIT 100 OFFSET $offset
```

Comment: you have categorias.seccion in the select fields and categorias.secion into the where, maybe it is the problem

Comment: The error mean that the query don't return a result so could be you have some error or don't matching condition ... eg: what mean the condition AND $ESTADO in you first?

Comment: @giuseppestraziota i found i had an error in the condition categorias.secion it was missing a C. It is: categorias.seccion
But now my error is that it doesnt find results..

Is my SQL QUERY sintaxys okay?

Comment: it seems ok, try to execute the query with the values instead of the params  to check if there are results that matching your conditions

Comment: @giuseppestraziota I have found the error, it wasn't categorias.categoria_nombre i needed to look for categorias.id
All my mistakes were about programming without having a break.

Thanks a lot, your responses made me found my mistakes.. :)

Comment: It happen, have a good work!